Virtual Agent with Google Dialogflow Billing Anomaly
I built a Twilio / Goggle Cloud DialogFlow integration last year.  It was my first experience with both Twilio or Google Cloud.  The client says it's been working well, but the Twilio bills have been abnormally high.
Anomaly in Billing
I found what appears to be the culprit (see attached image), but can't track down the cause.  These don't align with any sort of peak usage times and I didn't see anything in the call logs that coordinate with these spikes.  They occur maybe 2% percent of the time, but are responsible for 90% of the cost.
Is anyone familiar with what might be causing this, or what direction I should take to dig further into the issue?

This is not a support forum. Please open a ticket with Twilio

This is because sometimes users do not end their call due to which it costs you. Although the user is not aware that call is in-progress but that happens.
So it's best to use sys-noninput to check how many times the no-input is matched if the no-input is matched 3 times simply end the call. This method will help you reduce the cost.


Let me know how that goes out.

Aymal, thank you for your feedback.  The client did not end up approving any work to optimize the dialogflow / Twilio workflow.
